# Postfix+Dovecot Unix user authentication

Tags: server, postfix, dovecot, passwd-file

I want to set up a mailserver with postfix+dovecot+roundcubemail. And I don't want virtual users. Is it possible to use Unix users and somehow just include the /etc/passwd file for authentication/login?

The background is that I have several services installed on my server and all of them use Unix user authentication. For example, owncloud. So I want all of the users to be able to access all services with one login. I know this could be solved by LDAP but I am not smart enough to set up LDAP. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for PAM authentication. As far as I know (i.e. after a quick internet search), there's no built-in PAM module for postfix. However, it is available through SASL.

I've never tried this (as I use LDAP), but you might find these useful resources. After skimming them, they look like it's what you want.

- https://wiki.debian.org/PostfixAndSASL
- http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

  - specifically, http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#saslauthd_pam